# SQLLocal DB 2016 Unable to connect

Tags: sql-server, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

I am having issues connected with SQL 2016 MSSQLLocalDb from my application. The system is a Server 2012 and I have just deployed my web application to it. I have installed SQLLocaldb 2016.

Running

```
sqllocaldb info
gave this response:  The automatic instance MSSQLLocalDB was not created.
```

So I created the instance with the name MSSQLLocalDB.

But when I run the application I get this error: 
Using:
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local 
Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the 
Windows Application event log for error details.
    )
```

Changing Data source to named pipe gives this error:

Data Source=np:\.\pipe\LOCALDB#7A55F963\tsql\query

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing 
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error 
Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Hear is a screen shot of SQL Server Management Studio (un-able to connect as well) 
[image]

Can someone please help?

I can't open configuration manager either, when I try I get this error.

[image]

Comment: The event view has this error: Unexpected error occurred while trying to access the LocalDB instance registry configuration. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Answer (score 0):

Try browse: Server name -> Brose for more -> Database Engine.

Comment: It finds the server in question under Network server, but can't connect with same error as in the attached picture. Nothing in the local servers list.

Comment: Try to reinstall LocalDB and check if during istallation it finds this instance.

Comment: I'm trying to uninstall and then install localdb 2014 at the moment

Comment: Uninstalling localdb 2017 and installing 2014, results in the same issues. Still can't connect from SSMS. The instance files are created in the C:\Users\AAAAAAAA\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB folder

Comment: Any firewall? this is really wierd.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow into the firewall, what am I look for?  I can connect to another server which is running SQL express from the same SSMS.

Comment: Windows firewall is turned off.